# Extracting directory path from full file path without the file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a function that receives full file path as a string and the goal is to return just the file path without the filename. The goal also is to handle all file type such as Windows, Unix etc. I had to replace `\` with `/` which works fine for Windows file paths but seems unnecessary for Unix paths.

```
def get_path(file):
    file = file.replace('\\', '/')
    path = os.path.dirname(file)
    return path
```

Is there any way to extract the path without replacing the backward slash? 
Here's are two example input path strings

Windows: `'c:\\Program Files\\user\\file1.txt'`
Unix: `'file/path/name.txt'`

I have searched through stack but couldn't find any answer that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.path.split()`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split), it splits the path based on the operating system `python` is running on

> Note Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard library. The os.path module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths. However, you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is always in one of the different formats. They all have the same interface:
>   posixpath for UNIX-style paths
>
> - ntpath for Windows paths
> - macpath for old-style MacOS paths
> - os2emxpath for OS/2 EMX paths

What if you have windows path and you're running on Ubuntu/Linux, then you can use `ntpath` as said in the documentation just like so:

```
>>> import ntpath

>>> ntpath.split("c:\\Program Files\\user\\file1.txt")
('c:\\Program Files\\user', 'file1.txt')

>>> ntpath.split("file/path/name.txt")
('file/path', 'name.txt')
```

Comment: What benefit does `os.path.split` provide over `os.path.dirname` for getting the directory name?

Comment: As said by the OP, "the goal is to return just the file path without the filename."

Comment: i.e. the dirname?

Comment: And that's what `os.path.split()` returns the `dirname` as you call it and the `filename`. Am I righ?

Comment: Let's say I just wanted the `dirname`. Would I use `os.path.dirname`?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with no problem.

Comment: directly using `os.path.dirname` doesn't return the path from this windows path `"c:\\Program Files\\user\\file1.txt"`. that's why I had to replace `\`. @Anwarvic do you have any example file path that would fail if I use ntpath?  Both of my example path seems working

Comment: No, `npath` won't fail at any given **Windows** path as long as it's a correct path.

Comment: By the way, `os.path.dirname` failed at this specific path because the code is NOT running on windows. The `os` module detects that the operating system is not windows. So, this is not a valid path according to the `os` module.

Comment: so does that meansif I use `ntpath` no matter where the code runs it should return the correct path from any windows or UNIX like file path?

Comment: I think so... yeah. I've edited my answer to point out just that

Comment: @saz It will not work for _all_ unix paths. For example, `/home/user/c:\\foo\bar\baz` is valid in unix, but `ntpath.dirname` will return `/home/user/c:\\\\foo\\bar` instead of `/home/user`.

Comment: @hmm that covers my use cases that's why accepted that answer. But you are right. it's now concerning me. Not sure if there's any way to handle all unix paths. let me know if you have any clue.thanks